# How to merge three data frames using two variables based on conditions in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

R users,
I want to merge data from three different data frames (studentsPublic, studentsPrivate, studentsState) into one data frame called Final_Desired_df.
Final_Desired_df. I want to use either students' email addresses or their social security numbers (ssn) .  The example below illustrates what I need and also a description of the Final_Desired_df. Thanks in advance for assistance.

```
studentsPublic = randomNames::randomNames(10)
emailPublic = c('a@usa.com', NA, 'b@usa.com', 'c@usa.com', 'd@usa.com',NA, NA, 'e@usa.com', 'f@usa.com', 'g@usa.com')
examPublic = rnorm(10, mean=15, sd=5)
d1_PublicSchool = data.frame(studentsPublic, emailPublic, examPublic)

studentsPrivate = randomNames::randomNames(10)
emailPivate = c('t@usa.com', NA, NA, NA, 'd@usa.com',NA, NA, 'e@usa.com', 'f@usa.com', NA)
ssnPrivate = c(NA, 12, 34, NA,45, 67, NA, 32, 23, NA )
exanPrivate = rnorm(10, mean=15, sd=5)
d2_PrivateSchool = data.frame(studentsPrivate, emailPivate, ssnPrivate, exanPrivate)

studentsState = randomNames::randomNames(30)
emailState = c('a@usa.com', NA, 'b@usa.com', 'c@usa.com', 'd@usa.com',NA, NA, 'e@usa.com', 'f@usa.com', 'g@usa.com')
ssnState = c(NA, 12, 34, NA,45, 67, NA, 32, 23, NA)
sexState = rep(c('male', 'female'), 15,15)
d3_StateSchools = data.frame(studentsState, emailState, ssnState, sexState)
```

Final_Desired_df = should include all students from d1_PublicSchool whose email addresses are in the d3_StateSchools; and all students from d2_PrivateSchool whose either their emailPivate are in the d3_StateSchools OR their ssnPrivate are in the d3_StateSchools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I had to rename the columns to concatenate to final data frame and added a final step of removing duplicate rows.

```
# all students from d1_PublicSchool whose email addresses are in the d3_StateSchools
students_from_d1_in_d3_email<-d1_PublicSchool[which(d1_PublicSchool$emailPublic %in% d3_StateSchools$emailState),]

# add missing column of ssn as NAs
students_from_d1_in_d3_email<-cbind(students_from_d1_in_d3_email$studentsPublic,students_from_d1_in_d3_email$emailPublic,"ssn"=NA,students_from_d1_in_d3_email$examPublic)

# adjust column names to match
colnames(students_from_d1_in_d3_email)<-c("name","email","ssn","exam")

# all students from d2_PrivateSchool whose emailPivate are in the d3_StateSchools
students_from_d2_in_d3_email<-d2_PrivateSchool[which(d2_PrivateSchool$emailPivate %in% d3_StateSchools$emailState),]

# adjust column names to match
colnames(students_from_d2_in_d3_email)<-c("name","email","ssn","exam")

# all students from d2_PrivateSchool whose ssnPrivate are in the d3_StateSchools
students_from_d2_in_d3_SSN<-d2_PrivateSchool[which(d2_PrivateSchool$ssnPrivate %in% d3_StateSchools$ssnState),]

# adjust column names to match
colnames(students_from_d2_in_d3_SSN)<-c("name","email","ssn","exam")

# Final dataframe
Final_Desired_df<-rbind(students_from_d1_in_d3_email,students_from_d2_in_d3_email,students_from_d2_in_d3_SSN)


# Remove duplicate students in final dataframe
Final_Desired_df<-unique(Final_Desired_df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @dmuenzel. Another question for you, or for another helper, if you do not mind: Is there a way to merge two data frames using one of two columns? I want to merge df1 with df2 if df1$StudentID match df2$StudentID OR if df1$SSN match df2$SSN? Thanks in advance.